# Using lens to add key and value to a nested Map

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson, lenses

I am struggling to figure out an issue with manipulating JSON with Aeson lenses. My task is as simple as to add a key to a nested object in JSON. I was able to change the existing keyby means of:

```
> :set -XOverloadedStrings
> import Control.Lens
> import Data.Aeson
> import Data.Aeson.Lens
> "{ \"a\": { \"b\": 10 } }" & key "a" . key "b" .~ String "jee"
"{\"a\":{\"b\":\"jee\"}}"
```

But when I try to make it deal with the new key, it just silently fails to add it:

```
> "{ \"a\": { \"b\": 10 } }" & key "a" . key "c" .~ String "jee"   
"{\"a\":{\"b\":10}}"
```

Certainly it's me doing something wrong, but I figure I'm out of mana to understand what exactly.

Would you kindly point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As dfeuer noted, `at` can insert into maps, while `key` and `ix` merely traverse elements if they exist. We can do the following:

```
> "{ \"a\": { \"b\": 10 } }" & key "a" . _Object . at "c" ?~ String "foo"
"{\"a\":{\"b\":10,\"c\":\"foo\"}}
```

`at` is a lens focusing on `Maybe element`-s, and we can insert by setting to `Just` some element, and remove by setting to `Nothing`. `at "c" ?~ String "foo"` is the same as `at "c" .~ Just (String "foo")`.

If we want to do nested inserts, we can use [`non`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html) to define a default value to be inserted:

```
> "{ \"a\": { \"b\": 10 } }" & key "a" . _Object . at "c" . non (Object mempty) . _Object . at "d" ?~ String "foo"
"{\"a\":{\"b\":10,\"c\":{\"d\":\"foo\"}}}"
```

This is a mouthful, so we can factor some parts out:

```
> let atKey k = _Object . at k
> "{ \"a\": { \"b\": 10 } }" & key "a" . atKey "c" . non (Object mempty) . atKey "d" ?~ String "foo"
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a working example for my case and additional explanation!

Comment: It would make sense for (a version of) `.~/set` to return a `Maybe` for situations like this, where `set`s can be meaningless at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

`key` is based on `ix`, whose documentation indicates it isn't powerful enough to do what you want and points to `Control.Lens.At.at`. I'm pretty sure that should do the trick for you. The basic idea is that you start with the `_Object` prism to turn the JSON text into an object, then use `at key` to get a lens into that field *as a `Maybe`*. You can then change it to `Just` what you want.

This will work very well as long as all the objects along the path you wish to take exist. If you want to (potentially) start from nothing and create a chain of single-field objects, you will likely find things more annoying. Fortunately, you probably don't need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the reasons why `key` doesn't work for my case. I really tried to look into the source code, but it makes even less sense :-) Guess it takes time to get head around this.

Comment: @SkyWriter, if you're familiar with model/view terminology, you can think of `_Object` as providing a complete `Object` "view" of a `Text` model, but only if that `Text` successfully parses as an `Object`. Assuming the view succeeds, you can both inspect and modify the `Text` model through that view.